# Realtek RTL8723BE junk NIC Problems on Lenovo G50-30

Tags: lenovo, realtek, realtek-wireless

Realtek RTL8723BE NIC loses internet availability while connected. It works for a short period of time. A lot of other people reported this even after driver installation.... The same problems happened in Fedora RC. I am certain this is a software related issue. Upgrading to kernel 4.0.4 seemed to fix an annoying hardware lock in both distros. A new [Intel NIC](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/searchtools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=9673447&SRCCODE=WEBGOOPA&scid=scplp2779571&gclid=CNWAhbrw9cUCFVMXHwodqBEAmQ) is about to replace it. Any ideas?

Edit:
Thanks for your help! I decided to use Kernel 3.19.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install a better driver this way.

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

If you have Ubuntu 14.04, I also suggest installing updated firmware.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

**To fix hardware lock**, you need to install a patched `ideapad-laptop` module.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/ideapad-laptop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ideapad-laptop-dkms
```

I sent the patch upstream, it has been accepted, but it did not get into any of stable kernels yet.

At the moment I am writing this it is [COMMITED](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/commit/drivers/platform/x86/ideapad-laptop.c?id=4fa9dabcffc8e16601307d3d56b58c68d9716ba4) to linux-next.

But good news it is marked for `stable` and will get to all Ubuntu kernels some time.

**There is no guarantee that that module will work on 4.0.4**

But I think it will work. There is no need to install unsupported kernel for that.

**Update:** This issue with hardware blocking has been fixed in kernel 3.19.0-26. The `ideapad-laptop-dkms` can be removed if you upgraded to that kernel.

Comment: rtlwifi-new-dkms fails to resolve any issues.

Comment: This is the latest and best driver for that chip. It is not perfect, but works well for many people. If it is important, then it is a good idea to replace adapter with something else.

Comment: Hardware locks were enabled once again after rtlwifi-new-dkms was installed. A long time ago someone detailed online changing the default fixes the hardware lock without blacklisting. Not sure where the article is. I upgraded the kernel to 4.0.4 instead. This fixes the hardware lock issue. The internet was available after it connected for a short period of time. Without warning all availability stops while the NIC is still connected. The provided driver might work after changing the default. I am tempted to replace it altogether with a different NIC to prevent future headaches.

Comment: What is comp model? HW locks used to be on Lenovo.

Comment: Lenovo G50-30 http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/g50-30-notebook-lenovo/documents/PD100006?tabName=ProductParts

Comment: I made fix for this model. But has not reach 4.0.4 yet. It is in linux-next. I addet to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No need to update the kernel. Run this command:

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```